# Can't find haml-js templates during Jasmine test run

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, haml, jasmine

I'm trying to test some backbone.js views using Jasmine (via jasmine-headless-webkit).  Everything is working well, except that my haml-js templates aren't accessible under test.

The following code in my view works fine:

```
render: =>
  html = JST['views/avia_view_template']()
  $(@el).html(html)
```

... but when it's run as part of a Jasmine spec I get the following failure:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: JST in /home/duncan/avia/app/assets/javascripts/views/avia_view.js.coffee
```

I suspect I'm doing something wrong in `jasmine.yml`. I've explicitly included the template file it still fails:

```
src_files:
  - "vendor/**/*.{js,coffee}"
  - "lib/**/*.{js,coffee}"
  - app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/avia.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/underscore.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/backbone.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/views/avia_view_template.jst.hamljs
  - app/assets/javascripts/views/avia_view.js.coffee
```

Perhaps I'm just taking the wrong approach here ... should I be using Jasmine to stub & mock out the calls to JST and jQuery?  A strictly unit-testing approach says I should, in which case the lack of template access is a non-issue.

Any tips - either on my approach to testing, or the specific JST failure, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to stub, you just need to set up your asset paths correctly. In order to take advantage of the Sprockets integration in 0.8.0 and above, the best way to set up your jasmine.yml file would be like this:

```
src_dir: app/assets/javascripts
asset_paths:
- lib/assets/javascripts
src_files:
- "**/*"
```

This will set up Sprockets to look in `app/assets/javascripts` and `lib/assets/javascripts`, and will tell jasmine-headless-webkit to pull every possible file in both directories. Jasmine's normal file requiring wouldn't be used in this case, just Sprockets.

Then, set up your `require` statements like you would normally in your JS files. So in 'application.js.coffee':

```
#= require jquery-1.6.4
#= require avia
#= require underscore
#= require backbone
#= require jquery.jqGrid.min
#= require_tree .

alert "Look, Internet codes!"
```

And in `avia_view.js.coffee`:

```
#= require views/avia_view_template.jst.hamljs

class window.AviaView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['views/avia_view_template']
  ... code ...
```

Of course, those `.hamljs` templates won't get loaded unless a Sprockets-capable Haml processor has been loaded. So you would want to have a Gemfile that had at least this in it:

```
gem 'jasmine-headless-webkit'
gem 'haml-sprockets'
# also bring in backbone and jquery
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'backbone-rails'
```

Then, if your application itself knows what to do when those vendored JS gems are loaded, you could get rid of you own copies of jQuery and Backbone, and you'd also have `.hamljs` templates available. At that point, you should run using Bundler:

```
bundle exec jasmine-headless-webkit
```

Last thing, the best way to make sure everything's actually getting loaded is to use the list option:

```
bundle exec jasmine-headless-webkit -l
```

That will run everything through JHW's and Sprockets' file loaders and print out the order of files to be included. This will help diagnose `require` problems, since you always have to deal with both Jasmine-style and Sprockets-style loading in a single scenario. Setting up your src files to be loaded entirely via Sprockets simplifies the process a lot, so I would recommend a setup a lot like this one.

Comment: Thank you very much - that worked nicely.  Just one caveat though for anyone following these instructions: the `asset_paths` setting was added three days ago at the time of writing, so make sure you're using the very freshest jasmine-headless-webkit code.  I wasn't, and I was banging my head on the desk for a while until I figured it out.